# Byte swap real array

Tags: fortran

I need to perform a byte swap operation on a fortran array of real values. Is there a built-in for this in f90+? If not is there a simple do loop implementation that will accomplish this?

I know how to swap a single array of bytes using TRANSFER(). What I need to do is swap the bytes of a dimensioned array of REAL values. The linked question does not answer that question, please reopen.

Comment: No builtin byte swapping function.  You need to define which bytes you're needing to swap.  Should be trivial to implement with `TRANSFER` and the integer bits manipulation functions.

Comment: I use this module https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/master/src/endianness.f90  There might be something in some community efforts like stdlib too. Nothing in the standard.

Comment: @steve, TRANSFER works fine for swapping bytes of a _single_ byte array comprising a REAL. What I need to do is byte swap a dimensioned array of REALS.

Comment: So, write an elemental function that swaps the bytes with `transfer`.  Call the elemental function with the array.

Comment: @steve, do you agree that the link in the closure comments does not answer the question or show how to write the proposed elemental function?

Comment: It almost answers your question.  It shows a few methods for a single `real`.  You can wrap any of those methods into an elemental function that works on arrays.

Comment: @osprey What exactly do you want? If you want to swap each array element the same  way, there is no difference. It is exactly the same. See the link for the module I use, it is elemental already. I use it for arrays. What **exactly** do you want to swap? Be specific please.

Comment: Otherwise I can as well reopen and paste my code, but is it really worth it? My advise is: do NOT reopen, the answer is exactly the same, just with one keyword added in a trivial way.

Comment: @VladimirF, yes looking at your bitbucket repo was really helpful. Fortran is still pretty new to me, so I didn't know about elemental functions. Rewriting the subroutine I had written, which performed a byte swap (for endianness) on a single REAL, as an elemental function which operates on an array of REALs solved my issue. The problem I have is that the question was closed based on the content of the closure link Q/A which does not answer the question I had. I think I'd like it reopened so I can post how I changed the subroutine to an elemental to work for my situation.